# working on a tutorial for GPS Location mapping, semi confused

Tags: android

So this tutorial that I am using is not being as straight forward as I am hoping for. The next step requires the following:

"We need to create a class implementing abstract LocationListener class. This class will be registered with Location Manager to receive updates of location. We need to override all four methods of this class, namely onLocationChanged, onProviderDisabled/Enabled, and onStatusChanged. As we are just interested in getting location updates, we will modify the code of onLocationChanged to navigate to the new location received in the map view. This is achieved by calling animateTo method of MapController."

I would just like a little bit of advice as to if its a class I need to create on my own (new>Class) method, or is it just code I am supposed to add into another file.

Comment: The key statement is "create a class implementing abstract LocationListener class". So, yes you have to create your own class and implement that interface (LocationListener). To know more do a search for "java classes and interfaces".

Answer (score 1):

Its just a native method of a class, you don't have to create a new one for that. Rather you will override that specific method of a class.

The onLocationChanged, onProviderDisabled/Enabled, and onStatusChanged method are just like
the onCreate of your main activity.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial has a relatively simple example of how to obtain a gps fix in Android.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}   
}
```

Essentially you want to either create a class that implements LocationListener or have a nested class within your activity.

In either case you will need to override those methods in order to make use of changes in location.